# "context cancelled" error logged in Hyperledger Fabric peer node

Tags: kubernetes, hyperledger-fabric, docker-in-docker

I get the following error sometimes in my Hyperledger Fabric peer node (v1.4). Some times the system works ok after it but once I have seen that the ContractRouter is started completely after that error, when the chaincode needs to be executed. Any idea what this may be cause with? Can it be a problem if the underlying docker container running the chaincode being restarted? (That would be pod nid1-blockchain-hapeer1-mrrc-0.9.8 as shown in logs)

How can I check the logs in the DinD docker (I use Kubernetes) of the dockers running chaincode? (I'm using Java chaincode). thanks.

```
2020-01-24 11:57:23.623 UTC [chaincode] ProcessStream -> ERRO 1fc9e handling chaincode support stream: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
receive failed
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*Handler).ProcessStream
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/handler.go:442
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*ChaincodeSupport).HandleChaincodeStream
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/chaincode_support.go:191
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*ChaincodeSupport).Register
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/chaincode_support.go:196
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/accesscontrol.(*interceptor).Register
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/accesscontrol/interceptor.go:57
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer._ChaincodeSupport_Register_Handler
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer/chaincode_shim.pb.go:1069
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).processStreamingRPC
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:1124
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).handleStream
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:1212
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).serveStreams.func1.1
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:686
runtime.goexit
    /opt/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1337
2020-01-24 11:57:23.693 UTC [dockercontroller] func2 -> INFO 1fc9f Container nid1-blockchain-hapeer1-mrrc-0.9.8 has closed its IO channel
```

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: I didn't really. I found the problem that was causing the DinD docker container to be restarted. I haven't anyway found the way to get information about what is going on under the hood in that DinD. Sorry I can't be of much help for now.